# how to get full variable list from a list contains multiple df

Tags: r

I have a list of df, and now I would like to put all variables for each df into 1 variable `Varlist`, how should I do that at once?

If my list is `Filelist` and dfs are named as A, B, C, etc.

my ideal output will looks like:

[image]

Any idea on how to make it happen? map? lapply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not share any data but do you mean something like this?

```
Filelist <- list(mtcars = mtcars, iris = iris)
stack(lapply(Filelist, function(x) toString(colnames(x))))[2:1]

#     ind                                                        values
#1 mtcars        mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb
#2   iris Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species
```

With `purrr::map_df` -

```
purrr::map_df(Filelist, ~data.frame(Varlist = toString(colnames(.x))), .id = 'File')
```